# How to show/hide divs with a delay in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, delay, show-hide

I have some code that attempts to show and hide divs one after the other, after a delay.

```
$('#box1').delay(1800).hide('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box2').delay(1800).show('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box2').delay(1800).hide('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box3').delay(1800).show('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box3').delay(1800).hide('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box4').delay(1800).show('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box4').delay(1800).hide('slow');
delay(1800).$('#box1').delay(1800).show('slow');
```

The divs are not showing and hiding.  How do I get the divs to show and hide after a delay?

Comment: `delay(1800).$` is invalid syntax. remove the `delay(1800).` part at that spot.

Comment: but, even if i do remove it its still not working
the idea is each box to be afther the other hide

Comment: Right, it wasn't meant to be a solution, it was only intended to fix the immediate syntax error that will cause your code to not work at all regardless of the logic errors it contains otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User **Kevin B** suggested the following in the comments. This takes care of the verbose nature/pyramid of doom my original answer catered to.

```
$('#box1').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise().then(function(){
    return $('#box2').delay(1800).show('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box2').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box3').delay(1800).show('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box3').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box4').delay(1800).show('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box4').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise();
}).then(function(){
    return $('#box1').delay(1800).show('slow').promise();
});
```

Comment: This could be made a little cleaner looking (no pyramid of doom) using promise objects: http://jsfiddle.net/uXNjK/1/

Comment: Kevin, that is great. Thank you very much for showing me this. I'm going to include your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Is it possible the whole thing to loop, is there a goto function in jquery or somekind of while 1=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something more along the lines of this would be better:

```
// Go over each .box in the collection
$(".box").each(function ( i ) {
    $(this)
        // Show after index * 1800 (0 * 1800, 1 * 1800, 2 * 1800, etc)
        .delay( i * 1800 ).show("slow")
        // Hide after same calculation
        .delay( i * 1800 ).hide("slow");
});
```

Just give each box the `.box` class.